# can't create configurable product programatically

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, product-attribute

im create configurable product programatically. all works fine but attribute is not set to configurable product when i open product in admin is look like

see image.

[image]

how i can set attribute to configurable product..

i used this code to set attribute

```
$superAttributeIds = array('92');
$cProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1261);
$cProduct->getTypeInstance()->setUsedProductAttributeIds($superAttributeIds); 

$cProduct->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
try
{
        $cProduct->save();
}
catch( Exception $e) 
{
        echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
        foreach (array('size', 'color') as $attributeCode) {
            $usedProductAttributesIds[] = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $attributeCode)->getId();
        }

        $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->setUsedProductAttributeIds($usedProductAttributesIds);
        $configurableAttributesData = $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray();

        $configProduct->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
        $configProduct->setConfigurableAttributesData($configurableAttributesData);
```